# A numeric version of a sckit-learn tf-idf word-frequency array?

Tags: scikit-learn, numeric, unsupervised-learning

I'm trying to learn more about unsupervised learning in Python. When I was doing a couple of courses on DataCamp, I noticed that scikit-learn had feature extraction but it was only for text. However, what if the list I have is all numbers. Is there one for numeric lists?

Here's the example:

```
[12, 21, 3, 33, 42, 16, 10, 46, 32, 1, 17, 50]

[3, 18, 19, 21, 11, 44, 36, 17, 2, 42, 6, 11]

  ...  etc ...
```